# manage many documents scan with a java application

Tags: java, twain

I am trying to make an application to scan documents from a scanner and i have found an application based on the mmscomputing free library that i found in github https://github.com/ashishkataria/browserWebScanning

It shows a panel from where you can choose a scanner from a list of available ones and scan the document.

```
public void getScan() 
{

    try 
    {   
        scanner.acquire();
    } 
    catch (ScannerIOException e1) 
    {
        IJ.showMessage("Access denied! \nTwain dialog maybe already opened!");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}



 public Image getImage()
 { 
     Image image = imp.getImage();
     return image;
 }



public void update(ScannerIOMetadata.Type type, ScannerIOMetadata metadata) {



    if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.ACQUIRED)) 
    {   

if(imp!=null)
{
    jContentPane.remove(ipanel);
    jContentPane.remove(cpanel);
    jContentPane.remove(crpdpanel);
}


         imp = new ImagePlus("Scan", metadata.getImage());

         im = imp.getImage();

         imagePanel = new ImagePanel(im);
         imagePanel.updateUI();

         imagePanel.repaint();
         imagePanel.revalidate();

         ClipMover mover = new ClipMover(imagePanel);
         imagePanel.addMouseListener(mover);
         imagePanel.addMouseMotionListener(mover);

          ipanel = imagePanel.getPanel();

         ipanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue,1));
         ipanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Scanned Image"));
         ipanel.setBounds(0, 30,600, 600);
         ipanel.repaint();
         ipanel.revalidate();
         ipanel.updateUI();
         jContentPane.add(ipanel);
         jContentPane.getRootPane().revalidate();
         jContentPane.updateUI();

         cpanel = imagePanel.getUIPanel();
         cpanel.setBounds(700, 30,300, 150);
         cpanel.repaint();
         cpanel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue,1));
         cpanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Cropping Image"));
         cpanel.setBackground(Color.white);
         jContentPane.add(cpanel);


         jContentPane.repaint();
         jContentPane.revalidate();




        metadata.setImage(null);
        try {
            new uk.co.mmscomputing.concurrent.Semaphore(0, true).tryAcquire(2000, null);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            IJ.error(e.getMessage());

        }

    } 




    else if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.NEGOTIATE)) {
        ScannerDevice device = metadata.getDevice();
        try {
            device.setResolution(100);
        } catch (ScannerIOException e) {
            IJ.error(e.getMessage());
        }

          try{

          device.setShowUserInterface(true);
          device.setResolution(100); }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace(); }

    }


    else if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.STATECHANGE)) {
        System.out.println("Scanner State "+metadata.getStateStr());
        System.out.println("Scanner State "+metadata.getState());

        if ((metadata.getLastState() == 3) && (metadata.getState() == 4)){} 

    } else if (type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.EXCEPTION)) {
        IJ.error(metadata.getException().toString());

    }

}
```

I am trying  to make it handle multiple documents and save in a pdf file, this library handles only 1 document right now.
i want to know how can i save the images in a buffer or something else and rescan until the user is done .
and is there a function that can save those images in a pdf file ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Be sure to have a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). We help you with specific programming problems, but your question is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: What did you try? Which specific problems are you facing? Additionally, please don't drop loads of code here but try to boil it down to a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry i will try to edit to make it clear and my issue is there is a buffer where i can store images and ask for another scan until the user is done and then save the all in a same pdf document ? i just need a tip to know where to look